# jQuery Spinner not being sized by Bootstrap column

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to size a jQuery spinner using the Bootstrap grid system but it seems to ignore the class I assign to it.

I think it's due to the `span` that jQuery UI puts around the input. The span doesn't adopt the input's class and so auto-sizes.

How can I make the spinner use the correct width, i.e. the width of the column I'm trying to assign it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxHb3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the class to the spinner container after the initialization, like:

```
$('#input2').spinner({
    min: 1,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).closest(".ui-spinner").addClass('col-sm-2')
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/5L3VA/